# Repeating through an array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am playing about with AngularJS and have a problem with iterating through arrays.

I have the data below which contains a sub item called `tags` as an array:

```
$scope.documents = [{
    title: 'My First Report',
    tags: ['report', 'test'],
    modified: (new Date())
}, {
    title: 'My Second Report',
    tags: ['report', 'test'],
    modified: (new Date())
}];
```

What I would like to do is loop through each document and then loop through each tag.

I am able to iterate through the `documents` with no problem, but when I try looping through the `tags` property on a `document` it returns no results.

So far I have tried the below, which seems logical to me:

```
<li ng-repeat="document in documents">
  <p>{{document.title}}
    <li ng-repeat="tag in document.tags"> 
      <span>{{tag}}</span>
    </li>
   </p>
</li>
```

I've made a JSFiddle to show the problem I'm having:

[**View JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8VJ6S/)

Am I missing something?

Comment: Your code is okay only thing you have missed ul for li

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your syntax is not right, you are missing an `ul`, list elements need a container:

```
<div ng-app='AngularTestApp'>
    <div ng-controller="FileOpenCtrl">
        <ul class="unstyled">
            <li ng-repeat="document in documents">
                <p>{{document.title}}
                    <ul>
                        <li ng-repeat="tag in document.tags">
                            <span>{{tag}}</span>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/8VJ6S/3/

Comment: The positioning of `ng-repeat` was correct; your example is generating multiple `<ul>` tags. (The rest is fine)